# Android (Java) search for a string in json

Tags: java, android, json

I want to look for a particular country and once I find the country I want to print the related data to it. I have done this so far:

```
  boolean isFound = words.toString().indexOf("country one") != -1 ? true : false; //true
   if (isFound)
     {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//     System.out.println()

     } else {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NOT FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//       System.out.println()
     }
```

Here is the source JSON:

```
[
  {
    "country": "country one",
    "city": "city one",
    "Start Time": "21th December 2019 09:00 AM",
    "End time": "22th December 2019 03:00 PM"
  },
  {
   "country": "country two",
    "city": "city two",
    "Start Time": "23th December 2019 09:00 AM",
    "End time": "23th December 2019 03:00 PM"
  },
  {
 "country": "country three",
    "city": "city three",
    "Start Time": "24th December 2019 09:00 AM",
    "End time": "24th December 2019 03:00 PM"
  } 
]
```

It does not seem to work.

What I actually want is when I type in a country only that part of the JSON is printed out to me.

Comment: Hi @fish prawn. To clarify excatly what help you after, do you currently see "FOUND" and "NOT FOUND" printing when expected? Is this the first thing to solve? Or do you see this behaviour as expected and would like to improve it to print the correct block of JSON?

Comment: You should use Gson to parse JSON to list. Then you can iterate through the list of items and compare `country` field with you mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what I could make out, you need the info related to the "country one".. or the others based on country. You can accomplish it with this code:

```
public class ParseJSON {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String searchString = "two";
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(words);
    for(int k = 0; k < arr.length(); k++) {
        JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(k);
        if(obj.getString("country").contains(searchString)) {
            System.out.println("Country: " + obj.getString("country"));
            System.out.println("City: " + obj.getString("city"));
            System.out.println("Start Time: " + obj.getString("Start Time"));
            System.out.println("End Time: " + obj.getString("End time"));
          }
      }
  }
}
```

And the output is as below:

`Country: country one
 City: city one
 Start Time: 21th December 2019 09:00 AM
 End Time: 22th December 2019 03:00 PM`

I have used json-20090211.jar from this link..
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20090211

EDIT 1: I have assumed that the json is in a file... if available as a String then pass "words" directly to the JSONArray constructor and it will work.

Edit2: Since the OP has clarified that the json is in a string variable, the FileUtils is no longer needed.

Comment: itsays  cannot resolve symbol `Fileutils` 
do note i am using android

Comment: Is the json data in a file? please check my EDIT...if available as String then remove the line wirth FileUtils and pass it the variable as a JSONArray parameter.

Comment: @Malik Kumar 
it gives me an error ``` at 0 of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray```

Comment: Are you sure that the JSON shown above is an array with square brackets with nested objects? I have tried it on my machine ... it works.check your JSON.

Comment: the problem is that i want to search the entire string so forexample 
if i type `one` 
it should give me
`Country: country one`
` City: city one`
` Start Time: 21th December 2019 09:00 AM`
` End Time: 22th December 2019 03:00 PM`

Comment: There is no need to search the entire String when your search string contains "one" or "two" which is in the country property only. Will modify the solution and you will get the above answer as well.

Comment: please check the code now... as you can see I have searched for two this time.

Comment: thank you so much for your help i didnt even know how to start :)